# Router doesn't redirect user upon successful login

Tags: angular, routes

Can someone help me fix the routing on my angular application, it doesn't route the user upon successful login, the route it should automatically route to is called workbench, sorry for my english not my first language, thank you!

here is my code:

**login ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '@services/auth.service';
import { ObjPartyService } from '@services/obj-party.service';
import { ObjUserService } from '@services/obj-user.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  user = {
    username: 'TECHNICAL_USER',
    password: 'TECHNICAL_USER'
  };

  isLoading = false;
  message = null;

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService, private objPartyService: ObjPartyService,
              private objUserService: ObjUserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onLogin(): void {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.authService.logOut();
    this.authService.authenticate(this.user).subscribe(objUser => {

      this.objUserService.saveUser(objUser);

      this.objPartyService.getPrivatePerson().subscribe(userPerson => {
        this.objPartyService.savePrivatePersonToSessionStorage(userPerson);
        this.router.navigate(['workbench']);
      });

      this.isLoading = false;

    }, err => {
      this.message = 'Login failed: ' + err.error != null ?
        err.error.status + ' ' + err.error.error : 'Could not establish server connection.';

      this.isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  abortLogin(): void {
    this.isLoading = false;
  }
}
```

**app route**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
// Public Modules
import { HomeComponent } from './public/home/home.component';
import { ImprintComponent } from './public/imprint/imprint.component';
import { DataPrivacyComponent } from './public/data-privacy/data-privacy.component';
import { TechStackComponent } from './public/tech-stack/tech-stack.component';
// Auth Modules
import { AuthGuardService } from './services/auth-guard.service';
import { LoginComponent } from './public/login/login.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from './public/logout/logout.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './public/registration/registration.component';
import { UserProfileComponent } /*  */ from './protected/entities/static-data/user/user-profile/user-profile.component';
// // Protected Modules
import { WorkbenchComponent } from './protected/workbench/workbench.component';
// import { BusinessBaseComponent } from './protected/entities/party/business-base/business-base.component';
// import { MarketResearchComponent } from './protected/market-research/market-research.component';
import { ControlPanelComponent } from './protected/control-panel/control-panel.component';
import { LogComponent } from './protected/control-panel/log/log.component';
import { SettingsComponent } from './protected/control-panel/settings/settings.component';
import { OrderFormComponent } from '@protected/workbench/order-form/order-form.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
  { path: 'imprint', component: ImprintComponent },
  { path: 'data-privacy', component: DataPrivacyComponent },
  { path: 'tech-stack', component: TechStackComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent },
  { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
  { path: 'workbench', component: WorkbenchComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
  { path: 'user-profile', component: UserProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
  {
    path: 'control-panel', component: ControlPanelComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'log', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'log', component: LogComponent },
      { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent }
    ]
  }
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

if you need more to help me please let me know! thank you so much

Comment: Can you add your `app-router.module.ts` file here

Comment: There you go thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this routing. I hope it will work**

**login ts file**

```
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/workbench');
```

**app route**

```
  const routes: Routes = [

  {
  path:'', component: MasterComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard],
  children:[
  
  {path:'home',component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'workbench', component: WorkbenchComponent},

  ]

  },   

  {path:'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path:'', redirectTo:'/login',pathMatch:'full'},


  {path:'**',component: LoginComponent}

  ];
```

Comment: Hi i followed it and tried more guides online, it still doesn't work